# IntelliJ android app starts then gives error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am trying to run an android app on a USB Device Using IntelliJ.

It starts then it says: session "sessionname"; error.

it has worked on 2 android devices up to now :(

The error i get is:

```
01-30 14:20:01.160      522-522/? E/arm-runtime﹕ /mnt/sdcard is not mounted.
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
01-30 14:20:02.030      519-519/? E/Netd﹕ Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported
01-30 14:20:02.030      519-519/? E/Netd﹕ Unable to open quota2 logging socket
01-30 14:20:45.980      574-574/? E/dalvikvm﹕574 :: IS_UNIFIED_ARM_PROCESS=FALSE, debugFlags = 1
01-30 14:20:48.140      574-574/? E/BatteryService﹕ usbOnlinePath not found
01-30 14:20:48.140      574-574/? E/BatteryService﹕ batteryStatusPath not found
01-30 14:20:48.140      574-574/? E/BatteryService﹕ batteryHealthPath not found
01-30 14:20:48.140      574-574/? E/BatteryService﹕ batteryPresentPath not found
01-30 14:20:48.140      574-574/? E/BatteryService﹕ batteryCapacityPath not found
01-30 14:20:48.140      574-574/? E/BatteryService﹕ batteryVoltagePath not found
01-30 14:20:48.140      574-574/? E/BatteryService﹕ batteryTemperaturePath not found
01-30 14:20:48.140      574-574/? E/BatteryService﹕ batteryTechnologyPath not found
01-30 14:20:49.960      574-589/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
01-30 14:20:51.490      574-588/? E/HdIpc﹕Connect failed err = -1 errno = 110 (ETIMEDOUT). Timeout log will be logged only once per process
01-30 14:21:28.410      521-521/? E/PhonePolicy﹕ Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
01-30 14:21:34.650      522-522/? E/PhonePolicy﹕ Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
```

If anyone would be willing to help i would be VERY happy

Comment: Whatever you see there does not look related to your app and does not seem wrong. Try not to filter the log for just errors (or in a way that you only see messages from your app) and look at the timestamps to figure out what the error in your app is.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, when creating new activity, in xml file i named one button buttonNew, and in NewActivity.java I mistakenly entered wrong name of a button id.
In stead of writing:

```
newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);
```

I put

```
newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newButton);
```

Once I corrected it, everything was fine.

I figured out the hard way that you have to be very careful and make sure that you have strict naming convention, otherwise you will be lost forever.

Regards,